# Подскажите по настройке .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

3 день не могу решить проблему с 301 редиректом:
Redirect 301 /service/iphone-repair  https://мой-сайт/remont-iphone/
Redirect 301 /service/iphone-repair/remont-iphone-14-pro  https://мой-сайт/remont-iphone-14-pro/

При таком коде, редирет работает для страницы https://мой-сайт/remont-iphone/, а для второй страницы срабатывает таким образом: https://мой-сайт/remont-iphone/remont-iphone-14-pro/

То есть, /service/iphone-repair/ htaccess считает каталогом, хотя таковым не является.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)